# Can I present a UIViewController modally offscreen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I'm interested in knowing if it is possible to present a uiviewcontroller offscreen, so that the view controller will believe its on the screen, while nothing appears to the user.

I've tried manually call, viewDidLoad, loadViews ...  in the same order apple calls those methods, but it did't work out well.

ideas ?!

Comment: Another option would be to create a new `UIWindow`, and set your VC as  the `rootViewController`.  But I feel I must ask... why do you want to present a VC off-screen?  If it needs no user input to do whatever you want, it suggests that `UIViewController` is the wrong class.

Comment: @pbasdf I can't really create the ViewController because its one of apple's view controllers (like email view controller), and I need its functionality, not its UI :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I'm trying to integrate some functionality in apple UIs inside my own UI, I managed to interact with the Apple's UI programatically, and now I only need to remove it out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom segue and set the destination controller's frame off screen.  I don't even think you need to make the custom segue animated since the controller is off the screen the whole time.

I think there'll be an issue though with the source view controller still being on screen and receiving gestures.

Since the view controller is off screen, is there a reason why you need it to be a uiviewcontroller?

Comment: the problem is that I can't create an instance of the destination view controller via storyboard, its one of apple's ViewControllers, such as document view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to make (or fake) a parent-viewController/child-viewController relationship.  You aren't actually supposed to call those methods directly, as you can see in [Apple's docs on beginAppearanceTransition:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW86).

If you are a parent viewController, you are responsible for manually managing the views of your children.  In your case, you just want to convince it that it's being displayed (which I support because I love hacky stuff, but you should be careful with off-screen rendering in general), so you can experiment with it until you find the right amount of lying-to-your-children.

Comment: I'm going to test that today, wish me luck :)